# How to transfer files from windows to linux using ssh?

Tags: command-line, putty

I am using putty to connect to a linux computer using ssh. I am on a local windows machine that has a file. I want to transfer a file from my windows machine to the linux machine. How could I do this in command line without filezilla?

Comment: Is this question really about programming?

Comment: if he wants command line because he's scripting, it is.  Although it wasn't explicit

Answer (score 2):

If ftp server is running in your Linux box then you can transfer files with filezilla (since it is ftp client). If that is not the case then download WinSCP a gui software like filezilla but uses SSH to transfer files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already on windows why not use GUI based clients? [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) is a good free client for transfers over SSH. It can transfer multiple files and also has auto resume facility.

Answer (score 2):

Using Putty's PSCP command (which you can get from [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) you can copy the file to your Linux computer by doing:

```
pscp.exe file_to_copy username@server_name:/path/destination_file_name
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do that using winscp. The command will be:

From command promopt:

scp "C:\files*.*" username@linuxserver:/home/files/

Answer (score 0):

The `putty` equivalent to `scp` is `pscp`.  Get it where you got `putty`

`scp` is the ssh way to copy files to and from something running a ssh server.  So you could send your file from the windows machine to Linux on the windows command line